how to have next/save button inside a tab to proceed with next tab
Im new/noob to coding, I would just like to ask how can you make a tab proceed on the next tab once the user click next/save? and would it be possible to change the color of the finished tab? for ex. all the finished tab will be green while the current/unfinished will be yellow and the unopened is gray. please help, i cant not get pass this task huhu thank you so much in advance
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  display: block;
  background-color: inherit;
  color: black;
  padding: 22px 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 70%;
  border-left: none;
  height: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Vertical Tabs</h2>
<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>  
</body>
</html> 

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>


Hi, can you add your html code as well so it would be easy to understand and help out? Maybe a snippet would be a good idea to demonstrate what you have up to now

hello! i just update my post with an example of how my code is like. Thank u for replying!

I've edited your code to this. Hope it helps :)
Edited:
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box
        }

        body {
            font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
        }

        /* Style the tab */
        .tab {
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            width: 30%;
            height: 300px;
        }

        /* Style the buttons inside the tab */
        .tab button {
            display: block;
            background-color: inherit;
            color: black;
            padding: 22px 16px;
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            text-align: left;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: 0.3s;
            font-size: 17px;
        }

        /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
        .tab button:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
        }

        /* Create an active/current "tab button" class */
        .tab button.active {
            background-color: #e2f237;
        }

        .tab button.completed {
            background-color: #19ea82;
        }

        .tabcontent.active{
            display: block;

        }

        .tabcontent.not-active{
            display: none;
        }

        /* Style the tab content */
        .tabcontent {
            float: left;
            padding: 0px 12px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            width: 70%;
            border-left: none;
            height: 300px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var currentTab = 0; // Keep track of the current tab
    var tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    var tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");

    function openCity(evt, cityName) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            if (tablinks[i].id === cityName) {
                currentTab = i; // Update the current tab when a tab is clicked
            }
        }
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }


    function nextTab() {
        console.log(currentTab)
        console.log(tablinks.length-1)
        if (currentTab < tablinks.length - 1) { // Check if it's not the last tab
            tablinks[currentTab].className = tablinks[currentTab].className.replace(" active", " completed");
            tabcontent[currentTab].style.display = "none";
            currentTab++; // Move to the next tab
            tablinks[currentTab].className += " active";
            tabcontent[currentTab].style.display = "block";
        }
        if (currentTab === tablinks.length - 1) { // Check if it's the last tab
            var nextButton = document.getElementById("nBtn");

            if(nextButton.textContent === "Finish") {
                tablinks[currentTab].className = tablinks[currentTab].className.replace(" active", " completed");
            }

            console.log(nextButton)
            nextButton.textContent = "Finish"; // Change the button text to "Finish"
        }
    }
</script>

<h2>Vertical Tabs</h2>
<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks active" id="London" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
    <button class="tablinks" id="Paris" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
    <button class="tablinks" id="Tokyo" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="LondonC" class="tabcontent active">
    <h3>London</h3>
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="ParisC" class="tabcontent not-active">
    <h3>Paris</h3>
    <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="TokyoC" class="tabcontent not-active">
    <h3>Tokyo</h3>
    <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
<button id="nBtn" onclick="nextTab()">Next</button>

</body>
</html>




wow! tysm! would it be okay if I ask how can the last tab be a finish button instead of a next button? and would possibly turn green as well? since when it reaches the last tab it only turns yellow

I've edited the above block of code to also include the functionality mentioned

wow! tysm! u saved me alot of time! mw, still got alot to learn on script,, ty!
